# How Many tables can be selected when using ADF V2 copy data tool

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How many tables can be selected when using ADF V2 copy data tool? We can only select 1k tables when using ADF V1 
Can we edit the Copy Preview Pipline in V1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to a thousand tables can be selected in each ADFv2 Copy Data tool session. If copying more than a thousand tables is needed, multiple Copy Data tool sessions can be launched in multiple web browser tabs or windows. Check out the Copy Data tool documentation for other details (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool).

The resultant ADFv2 JSON configurations created by Copy Data tool can be further edited with ADFv2 UI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal#test-run-the-pipeline).

Comment: Correct, each Copy Data tool session will create one or more pipelines. Each pipeline can contain up to 30 (table) copy activities (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#data-factory-limits). Instead of a flat list of copy activities and pipelines, ADFv2 UI provides another config option for multi dataset copy with a ForEach loop activity and a parameterized copy activity as loop body (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal). Also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers.